# How this expression is going to sort the results sorted(list1 ,key = lambda x:-x[0])

Tags: python

```
data = sorted(zip(list1,list2),key = lambda x:-x[0])
```

how this expression is going to sort the results . if we have used x[0] and x[-1] the results would be forward and backward but here we are using -x[0].

Comment: `x[-1]` does not sort backwards; it sorts on the element from `list2` rather than the element from `list1`. `-x[0]` *does* sort backwards, assuming that `x < y` implies `-x > -y`.

Comment: `-x[0]` is sorting backwords by the first (zeros) element. `x[-1]` is sorting "forwards" by the last element (second in this case - from `list2`)

Comment: If you want to sort backwards, use the `reverse` keyword argument instead of trying to manipulate the key value.

Comment: What is preventing you from testing this yourself?